# Angular js scope var value in iframe

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, angular-routing

I am working with angular js . I have a controller "youTubePlayerCtrl", in this controller i have $scope.videoID which contains the youtube video id. I am able to get this value in belows div in h1 block . but i am not able to get {{videoID}} in iframe, can any one help me how to fix this.

```
<div ng-controller="youTubePlayerCtrl">
    <h1>{{videoID}}</h1>
    <iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="auto"
        height="auto" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/{{videoID}}"
        allowfullscreen frameborder="0"> </iframe>
</div>
```

This is the error log:

> [$interpolate:noconcat]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$interpolate/noconcat?p0=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fembed%2F%7B%7BvideoID%7D%7D
>       at Error ()
>       at http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.min.js:6:453
>       at g (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.min.js:69:467)
>       at b.push.compile (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.min.js:54:6)
>       at l (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.min.js:47:124)
>       at f (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.min.js:41:361)
>       at l (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.min.js:47:64)
>       at f (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.min.js:41:361)
>       at http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.min.js:40:434
>       at http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/angular-route.min.js:7:148  angular.js:7861 (anonymous
>   function)

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wPRUC/) (not working)

Thanx

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y4aKC/1/

Comment: Try `ng-src` : `ng-src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/{{videoID}}"`

Comment: @Cherniv What is the difference between them ng-src & src ? just a question .

Comment: @Anurag-Sharma from documentation: *Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in a src attribute doesn't work right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text {{hash}} until Angular replaces the expression inside {{hash}}. The ngSrc directive solves this problem.*

Comment: @Cherniv thanx, i tried ng-src but it is also giving error.

Comment: This is the error log : Error: [$interpolate:noconcat]  [$interpolate:noconcat] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$interpolate/noconcat?p0=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fembed%2F%7B%7BvideoID%7D%7D
    at Error (<anonymous>)

Comment: @Cherniv i edited the question and put the error log

Comment: @ArunPJohny it is only showing the youtube player but not playing video.

Comment: because the `videoID` is not valid

Comment: @ArunPJohny yes , i checked that, it is working. but why it is not working for my case.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y4aKC/2/

Comment: i checked your code on my Ide and it is not working. dont know why, it is well running on jsfiddle, i copied the same code. can you tell me what angular js files i have to put in my page.

Comment: @mb21 I reserched and found that when i am usining my module with ngRoute And ngSanitize then it is not playing video . var app = angular.module('my-app', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize'], function () {

})

Comment: There is the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19312045/angularjs-with-i-frame

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**First**: you need to use `ng-src` instead of `src` as @Cherniv suggested in a comment to your question. Read more [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSrc).

**Second**: you cannot concatenate the URL inside the source attribute for security reasons: you must concatenate the URL in Javascript in a scope variable e.g. `fullURL` and then `ng-src="{{fullURL}}"`. Read more [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3679).

**Third**: if Strict Contextual Escaping (SCE) is enabled ‒ and Angular v1.2 ships with SCE enabled by default ‒ you need to whitelist the URLs. Read more [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$sce) and [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$sceDelegateProvider).