# AngularJs with iframe

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, youtube-javascript-api

Why [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wPRUC/) is not working? I am not able to get value of `videoId`.  If I remove `ngRoute` from module then it is working fine.

Comment: You haven't defined ngRoute anywhere.

Comment: @BCotter ngRoute is a module coming from angular.route.js file.

Comment: The link of `angular-route.min.js` display "404 Not Found".

Comment: @EpokK i have the file in my local machine, can u tell me how i can add that file to this fiddle. i am knew to jsfiddle. thanx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `ng-src` like this:

```
<div ng-controller="AppController">
    <h1>{{videoID}}</h1>
    <iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="auto"
    height="auto" ng-src="{{videoID}}"
    allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0"> </iframe>
</div>
```

and

```
var app = angular.module('my-app', []);
app.controller('AppController', function ($scope, $sce) {  
    $scope.videoID = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://www.youtube.com/embed/C0DPdy98e4c');
});
```

See [this documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24sceDelegateProvider#resourceUrlWhitelist).

Comment: i also tried that but it was not working, my main problem is ngRoute , i have to use it for my views routing purpose

Comment: I tried $scope.videoID = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('C0DPdy98e4c'); but it didn't work and then i use $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://www.youtube.com/embed/C0DPdy98e4c"); then it worked, i dont know why it is not working with only id, but i am accepting your answer.

Comment: It doesn't work with just the id because it isn't a URL.