# "ng-src" property doesn't work all the time, "src" property does

Tags: angularjs

This code doesn't work all the time. Sometimes I get a 404 error.

```
<iframe ng-src="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/{{vid.id}}?autoPlay=0" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

This code works all the time.

```
<iframe src="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/{{vid.id}}?autoPlay=0" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I'm not sure I understand the purpose of ng-src anymore. Is it because it's an iframe?

Comment: Take a look , little bit different approach: http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/tkRnp/

Comment: That's an interesting approach, but it works perfectly with "src", so I think I'll stick with it. My question is: Why does it work? :D

Comment: ng-src should work, but if you're using an explicit link like that one then ng-src provides no benefit over src anyway - ng-src is for ensuring that {{ expressions }} are resolved before the link is displayed

Comment: Actually, your solution is better because I can check if the id exists (controller side).

Comment: @JMaylin: 
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19289402/angular-js-scope-var-value-in-iframe
 Apparently string urls can't be concatenated in the src property for security reasons.