# How to append parameters to iframe src Url in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an iframe control in View.

```
<iframe width="100%" height="800" ng-src="{{IframeSrcUrl}}"></iframe>
```

In the controller, I have a scope variable like below. But the iframe is not getting the url from scope variable. Also, how do we append additional query string parameters in the controller?

```
$scope.IframeSrcUrl = 'https://mmr.com';
```

Thanks!

Comment: SCE maybe the reason for this check, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19289402/angular-js-scope-var-value-in-iframe

Comment: ng-src="IframeSrcUrl" should be your markup. Since ng-src is an angular specific attribute, it won't require {{}} interpolation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use $sce service for this for example:-

```
<iframe width="100%" height="800" ng-src="{{IframeSrcUrl | trustAsResourceUrl}}"></iframe>


app.filter('trustAsResourceUrl', ['$sce', function($sce) {
    return function(val) {
        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(val);
    };
}])
```

Comment: @squiroid hey I had the same problem and your answer solved it. But there's one problem though. I have a list  of items and on clicking each item, the frame should be opened and the src changes dynamically.
But, on clicking the item iframe reloads on its own, which disturbs the iframes opened. What shall I do now?