# How to insert longitude & latitude in iframe in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, iframe, maps

Hei

I am using angular and trying to implement `iframe` in it . I'ave tried many ways to insert `longitude` and `latitude` which are coming from database but whenever try to write something like this I get error.

what I tried

```
<iframe width="100%" height="250" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q={{product.mall.lat}},{{product.mall.long}}&amp;key= key"  allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I get this error when i tried the above way

```
[$interpolate:noconcat]
```

Normal `iframe`

```
<iframe width="100%" height="250" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=40.7127837,-74.0059413&amp;key= Akey"  allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

use ng-src instead of src.

you cannot concatenate the URL inside the source attribute for security reasons: you must concatenate the URL in Javascript in a scope variable e.g. fullURL and then ng-src="{{fullURL}}".

if Strict Contextual Escaping (SCE) is enabled ‒ and Angular v1.2 ships with SCE enabled by default ‒ you need to whitelist the URLs.

Reference [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19289402/angular-js-scope-var-value-in-iframe)
[Angular js scope var value in iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19289402/angular-js-scope-var-value-in-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

Now its work, you need to wrap url into a method, that make it as a trusted url source

in html

```
     <iframe width="100%" height="250" frameborder="0" style="border:0" ng-src='{{getTrustedUrl("https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q="+product.mall.lat+","+product.mall.long+"&key=AIzaSyCaG_LpOazepPve-DlVH1TuxxkBVseOGd0")}}' allowfullscreen>

    </iframe>
```

add this function to your controller

```
  $scope.getTrustedUrl = function(src) {
  return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its already been answered in another Question

[AngularJS multiple expressions concatenating in interpolation with a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23405162/angularjs-multiple-expressions-concatenating-in-interpolation-with-a-url)

More details 
[Strict Contextual Escaping](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)

Answer (score 0):

This is What My Mentor did

In my controller function where I was getting `long` & `lat` He did something like this

```
$scope.single_product = function (product_id) {
        $http.get('url' + product_id + '?expand=product_variants,product_variant_options,photos,shop,mall',
                {headers:
                            {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                'Authorization': $rootScope.keyword_auth_token}
                })
                .success(function (data) {
                    $scope.product = data;
                    $scope.photo = $scope.product.photos;   //Storing photos in phot object
                    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.photo.length; i++) {
                        slides.push({path: $scope.photo[i].path, id: currIndex++}); //I already mentioned slides as an array
                    }
                    console.log(slides);
                    console.log($scope.product);
                    var compile_map = '<iframe width="100%" height="250" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q='+$scope.product.mall.lat+','+$scope.product.mall.long+'&amp;key= AIzaSyCaG_LpOazepPve-DlVH1TuxxkBVseOGd0"  allowfullscreen></iframe>';
                    angular.element($document[0].querySelector('#map_image')).append(compile_map); //This function will run only and load the html if it has long and lat
                })
                .error(function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
    };
```

and then in `html` simply that

```
<div id="map_image"></div>
```

It works like a charm

Comment: @aravind.udayashankara   have a look dear